# Can't install freeglut3-dev or libglfw-dev due to unity-control-center dependency issues

Tags: 14.04, unity, package-management, dependencies, unity-control-center

I'm trying to install 2 different packages: `libglfw-dev` and `freeglut3-dev`

When I run:

```
sudo apt-get install libglfw-dev
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install freeglut3-dev
```

I get the following error:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 unity-control-center : Depends: libcheese-gtk23 (>= 3.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libcheese7 (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

I've tried

```
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

but nothing changes. Unity's control-center works fine running from console and from launcher. It just won't let me install these two packages.

Comment: One question, you're using 14.04.1 or 14.04.2?

Comment: I'm using 14.04.2

Comment: Thanks, good to know I'm not alone, I have opened a bug [here](http://pad.lv/1428972).

Comment: Commented on it. Hopefully it's fixed soon.

Comment: @SylvainPineau This worked for me. This can be closed as a duplicate.